# Should I implement `serialVersionUID` on interfaces?

Tags: java, serialization

Should I add the `serialVersionUID` field when creating an *interface* that extends Serializable?

My IDE (Netbeans 8.2) complains that the field is missing. However, to my understanding, `serialVersionUID` is only applicable to non-abstract classes (the specific classes that will be instantiated during deserialization).

**If** `serialVersionUID` is necessary, what should I do about interfaces that extend interfaces? Normally, this field is declared in every class down the class heirarchy. While this is also possible for interfaces, it leads to a different IDE warning that fields hide fields.

Comment: Once you understand the purpose of `serialVersionUID`, you will get answer. [Here it is described well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It protects you how exactly?

Comment: @EJP: yes, you are right. Comment retracted, and apologies to the original poster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you should not. The `serialVersionUID` of an interface is nowhere taken into account during the serialization or deserialization process. It is pointless. `serialVersionUID` is for `Serializable` *classes.*

Comment: @Eugene No. Static variables are not serialized, and the `serialVersionUID` of a `Class` is given by `Class.serialVersionUID`.

Comment: @Eugene The code in the comment is not legal Java, so it is pointless to consider it further; but `Class<ITest> c` already has a `serialVersionUID` member, because it is an instance of `Class`. As I already stated. And this has exactly nothing to do with interfaces, which is what both the question and my answer are about.

Comment: you're right. 4 years ago I did not see this, now I realize I was wrong. I can't upvote this twice unfortunately.

Comment: With java 8, if your interface has any `default` methods, you will still need `@SuppressWarnings("serial")` due to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8191637